# Including a Month Calendar in a Windows Form always causes a System.ArgumentException. How to fix?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, monthcalendar, .net-4.6.1

I am using Visual Studio 2019 with .NET Framework 4.6.1.

If I do the following:

1. Make a new project using the 'Windows Form App (.NET Framework)' template.
2. Select the .NET Framework 4.6.1. Later exploration has found that 4.7.2. will also suffice.
3. Open up the newly created Form1 in design view.
4. In Form1, use the GUI to add a Month Calendar.
5. Set my Exception Settings to break on any exception.
6. Run the program.

Then I always get a `System.ArgumentException` from `Application.Run(new Form1());` reporting that "Value does not fall within the expected range". When you look very closely at the call stack, you will see that the true source of the error is from `System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.AccessibleObject.Accessibility.IAccessible.get_accChild(object ChildID)`. Once this exception has been thrown, your debugger will be stuck re-throwing it eternally.

Are there any simple fixes for this? Wrapping the source of the exception in a `try`/`catch` block does not stop the debugger from breaking. I can tell the debugger to ignore exceptions of this type from `System.Windows.Forms.dll`, but ignoring the problem is not a solution to it.

Comment: "ignoring the problem is not a solution to it" why not? It's a first-chance exception which is handled by someone else's code, why do you care?

Comment: @Charlieface How do I know that the exception is handled elsewhere?

Comment: Well if you turn off first chance exceptions do you get an Unhandled Exception box?

Comment: @Charlieface I've not encountered the term "first chance exceptions" before, so I may be misunderstanding you. Is your point that if I've both ignored that exception and not seen an Unhandled Exception box after doing so, then the exception must be handled in the internal Windows Forms code so I have nothing to worry about? If so, then I can confirm that I do not get an Unhandled Exception box.

Comment: Yes correct. VS can catch a First Chance Exception, which is before any `catch` has run. If there is no `catch` you get a different box for an Unhandled Exception. No don't worry about it, it's probably only a slight performance issue. Might be worth actually doing some debugging with External Code switched on, and step through the WinForms code to find out why it's throwing in the first place.

Comment: @Charlieface Unless someone has a magic answer that makes the exception go away, what you've said is probably the closest to an answer that anyone's going to get. Feel free to post it as one.

Comment: I must say, I cannot replicate this on .NET 4.8.1. Are you really running 4.6.1 it's way out of date now?

Comment: @Charlieface Unfortunately, yes. I've got a strong temptation to nag my employer about it. If there's any evidence that this bug was fixed between versions, then that would also answer my question. There was nothing blatant in the changelogs about this change, although the changelog for 4.7.1 mentions MonthCalendar. If I had to guess, version 4.7.0 will have the bug but 4.7.1 won't.

Comment: You can always try on another machine with 4.8.1 installed (it would be anyway if your Windows was up to date, as it's packaged into Windows updates. I hope you're not using Windows 7....)

Comment: @Charlieface Luckily, we're all on Windows 10, so all that I need to check is if my employer allows me. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Charlieface Darn it. I still get this issue on 4.7.2., which is as far as I can go.